# How to use “wish” in a sentence?

Tags: subjunctives, wish

A friend of mine will organize an event in London. Because I am living in Paris, I would like to say that

> I **wish** this event was also in Paris.

Do you think that my sentence is correct?

Comment: Yes. Some people would insist on _were_, for a counter-factual wish; but many people today will say _was_.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine in spoken English but it's not in written English. It should be:

> I wish this event **were** also in Paris.

If you look into the Collins Dictionary [here](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/wish), you'll find the following explanation:

> If you wish something were true, you would like it to be true, even though you know that it is impossible or unlikely.
>
> **I wish that I could do that.** [VERB that]
>
> **I wish it weren't true.** [VERB that]